# How to pre-select a server in a list of server in Swagger-ui?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springdoc

How to pre-select a chosen server in a list of servers when visiting the swagger-ui page?

I use Spring boot, and Springdoc to generate the swagger-ui. I have the following bean to add server list to swagger-ui:

```
@Bean
public OpenApiCustomiser openApiCustomiser() {
    return openApi -> openApi
            .servers(List.of(
                    new Server()
                            .url(localUrl)
                            .description("localhost"),
                    new Server()
                            .url(dsoUrl)
                            .description("DSO"),
                    new Server()
                            .url(iftUrl)
                            .description("IFT"),
                    new Server()
                            .url(prodUrl)
                            .description("PROD")));
}
```

On all environment hosts it will start by default from `localhost` option:

[image: Swagger-ui section for list of servers]

I want that on every environment host the swagger-ui shows the right url preselected. Is it possible? (The solution with list ordering differently on different environment hosts is not interesting for me, I want the list to keep one order on all envs).

Comment: The code sample you posted is just an interface to configure OpenAPI. The documentation talks about providing server(s) but does not seem to provide the option you are looking after: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/api-host-and-base-path/

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing the `localUrl` variable and instead use the one generated by swagger open api.

```
@Bean
public OpenApiCustomiser openApiCustomiser() {
    Server generatedServer = openApi.getServers().get(0);
    return openApi -> openApi
        .servers(List.of(
                new Server()
                        .url(generatedServer.getUrl())
                        .description("Generated URL"),
                new Server()
                        .url(dsoUrl)
                        .description("DSO"),
                new Server()
                        .url(iftUrl)
                        .description("IFT"),
                new Server()
                        .url(prodUrl)
                        .description("PROD")));
}
```

Another thing you can do is have your server list come from your properties file instead.

Comment: This does not solve the issue. I want on each environment the swagger-ui shows the right url preselected. Say on IFT env - the swagger has IFT preselected, but at the same time, it keeps its third place in the drop-down list.